# GDB "server" command

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

During usage of ConqueGDB I noticed that it sends following commands:

- server backtrace
- server break
- server <anything>

I'm wondering what is the purpose of the `server` keyword here. Alone it returns:

> Undefined command: "server".  Try "help".

With other commands like those mentioned before it looks like the word is just ignored.

Comment: @ks1322 I don't think the `vim` tag is needed here. My question is not related to `vim` itself.

Comment: When I googled "ConqueGDB", I found this [vim plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Conque-GDB), so I decided that it is related to vim. If it is not, feel free to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server` prefix can be used to prevent a command from being put into the command history, and to avoid having it be available for command repetition.  This is useful for front ends that want to run some commands without interfering with whatever the user might be doing.  This is [documented in the manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Server-Prefix.html).